# Order list and current page using Jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I need some help in Jquery. I'm listing all my post title from a specific category.

But when the page is loading, I wish the current post title to display in the middle ( and to add a class for this element ). Something like this:

[image]

My php code looks like:

```
    <div class="opacity cat">
        <div class="inner-home">
            <?php
            $category = new WP_Query( 'cat=12' ); ?>
            <p><?php echo get_cat_name(12) ?></p>

            <ul>

                <?php while($category->have_posts()) : $category->the_post(); ?>

                    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
                <?php endwhile;
                    wp_reset_postdata();
                ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I think we can do this using Jquery, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While, with Jquery lots of things can be achieved, i am not convinced that your problem is somewhat related to that.

As far as i understand from your question, and from the comments what you need to do is create an array of static posts:

```
$posts_array = array(197,199,201); //Just change with the ID's of your static posts
```

Remove the current post from the array so that we can isolate the other posts.

```
if (($key = array_search($post->ID, $posts_array)) !== false) {
    unset($posts_array[$key]);
}
$posts_array = array_values($posts_array); // Start from zero index.
```

Call the other posts, which are not the current:

```
$post_prev =  get_post($posts_array[0]);
$post_next =  get_post($posts_array[1]);
```

And finally, put them into their respective positions:

```
<div class="opacity cat">
        <div class="inner-home">
            <ul class="post_links_container">
                <li class="other-post-class">
                    <a href="<?=$post_prev->guid;?>"><?=$post_prev->post_title;?></a>
                </li>
                <li class="current-post-class">
                    <a href="<?=$post->guid;?>"><?=$post->post_title;?></a>
                </li>
                <li class="other-post-class">
                    <a href="<?=$post_next->guid;?>"><?=$post_next->post_title;?></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And of course, you need to style it with css:

```
ul.post_links_container {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 200px;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0px;
}
ul.post_links_container li {
    padding: 20px;
}
li.other-post-class {
    font-size: 14px;
}
li.current-post-class {
    font-size: 24px;
    padding-top: 0px !important;
}
```

Hope it works, you can play with css to do as you like. This is just for starter.

> IMPORTANT NOTICE: This solution is only for 3 posts which are also
>   static. Optimal for this question, but may not work for other cases.

Comment: If what you're asking is something like, previous and next posts, than it is a different story.

Comment: Thanks you :)  for this step I thought tout something like that. But m'y problem is how tout display the current li in the Middle ?

Comment: I get it. This can be done with Jquery, as well as php and css.

Comment: As far as i understand, let's say you have 10 posts in order. And current post is let's say the fourth. You would like to display it in the middle, and next to the current post, there should be previous(3rd) and next(5th). Am i correct?

Comment: I have 3 posts, the current is in the middle and the previeous on left and the next on right yes :)

Comment: so any idea ruzgar   ?

Comment: I am trying to understand what you are trying to do. If you want to show only 3 post, then why do you use `while loop`. Just `echo` **current, previous and next** posts. And put a `class` to current post. Display tjem `flex`, and of course change the `font size`.

Put the current post in the 2nd `<li>`. And you're done.

Comment: Thanks i will try :)

Comment: So i've jsut try with a loop with the prev and next post, but the result is not good; I have something  like this:

Page 1: POSTA / POSTB (current) / POSTC
Page 2: POSTA(current)/POSTB
Page 3: POSTB/POSTC(current)

So the loop stop and not begin again if previous or next is empty

I wish something like this: 

Page 1: POSTA / POSTB (current) / POSTC
Page 2:  POSTB / POSTA (current) / POSTC
Page 3:  POSTB / POSTC (current) / POSTA

Comment: Now i get it. You do not have more than 3 posts do you? If that's the case than you can do it. But if there are 4 posts everythings change.

Comment: One more question. Are these posts static? I mean, will their ID change?

Comment: This is important because if they are static you do not have to use `$category->have_posts()` And use `get_post( $id );` instead. But only if there are only 3 posts and they are all static.

Comment: Or you can still use the loop, and remove the current post from the loop array. And than print them to their respective locations.

Comment: Yep it's static it's always the same posts Ids, but off course the next and prev links change on each page (cause of the current post)

Comment: I edited my answer. Please check it out. It works as expected. But do not forget to change the ID's of your posts, with the numbers above.